# Firebase ID token has invalid signature even on jwt

Tags: node.js, firebase, jwt

**Firebase ID token has invalid signature**

Hi all, I'm somehow new to NodeJS and I've only used Google Firebase a few times.
Now, I'm trying to verify an idToken generated using `getIdToken()` method whenever a user signs up or signs in. The token generation works fine but if I try to use this token to authorize a user `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` on another route, I get this error **Firebase ID token has invalid signature** on Postman. I tried to verify the token on jwt.io as well, it gave error **Invalid Signature**.

I tried switching to different algorithms, some eventually made the token valid on jwt, but there is usually a VERIFY SIGNATURE box by the bottom-right which I don't really know what to fill there. Well, I've tried copying different newly generated valid tokens by jwt after changing algorithm, but I still get **Firebase ID token has invalid signature** from Postman.

Does anyone know what the problem may be? Please help.

Comment: to verify a token on jwt.io you first need to select the algorithm, then paste the secret or public key into the field in the VERIFY SIGNATURE box in the lower right and then paste the token into the left part of the debugger. For the rest of the question it's hard to tell without knowing more. But for verification you alwasy need the secret or public key.

Comment: Do you know the precise part to get the public or secret key? Thanks for your response.  **EDIT**    Also, the tutorial I am following, the Classed guy didnt face that error, neither did he provide or mention any key.

Comment: sorry, no idea about firebase

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem comes from the Firebase Emulator Auth. The Firebase-hosted Auth is unable to verify JWT token generated by the Firebase Emulator Auth.

Comment: has this been fixed? how are we supposed to maintain a testbed emulator if we can't test authentication? any workarounds?

Comment: any news here? still facing the same issue.

Comment: All else failed. Restarted my computer and that solved the issue for me. My guess is the emulator didn't shut down all the way.

Comment: i ended disabling auth emulator locally and leaving my local emulators authenticate against the real firebase auth

Answer (score 7):

**To verify the token manually** on jwt.io, you need to grab one of the public keys from google: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

To choose the correct key, find the one that corresponds to your `kid` from jwt.io.

[image]

Paste in the correct corresponding value and now your token should verify correctly (be sure to clear out any `\n` characters):

[image: valid sig]

**For easier programmatic verification**, the "JWK URI" is https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Genius Hawlah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803294/14443796) answer, the problem is the Firebase Emulator Auth. As a workaround I suggest to start emulators without the Auth one with the *--only* flag, for example `firebase emulators:start --only firestore,functions`, and authenticate with a user you have in the production Authentication

Comment: I had this issue as well. Even simply _starting_ the emulator auth (but not using it) can mess up the system. E.g. for me, saying `firebase emulators:start --only firestore,auth` broke the system, but `firebase emulators:start --only firestore` didn't, even though I wasn't using the auth emulator in the application code (e.g. by setting the env var, calling `useEmulator`, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, verifyIdToken function throws "Firebase ID token has invalid signature" each time for valid tokens when used in Firebase Emulator locally. I fixed this problem by starting using firebase hosted auth instead of emulator auth (remove auth property from firebase.json). Also, I reported the bug to Firebase.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR;

Prefer `log` from **dart:developer** over <del>`print`</del> and <del>`debugPrint`</del>.

---

I was not using the emulator...

I'm new to Firebase and have experienced this, and even upvoted  [GeniusHawlah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803294/3748178) as [Taras Mazurkevych's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803162/3748178) answers... But couldn't find anything in the Firebase setup related to the simulator that I did.

So it happened I was testing my firebase using a truncated JWT token, printed from Dart's <del>`debugPrint`</del> (which <del>limits</del> **truncates** output). I was successful in using `log` from **`dart:developer`**!

I was enlightened by https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665#issuecomment-456858672.

Comment: Thanks man! After 2 hours digging everywhere, this was the only answer that solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/b2a28aee5cac172ed183bc47f71a55b31f79696a/src/auth/base-auth.ts#L212), the `firebase-admin` package behaves differently when there is an Auth emulator available. You can either not start it to begin with or make it undiscoverable by removing its address from `process.env`.

```js
delete process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST
```

Source reference:

```
public verifyIdToken(idToken: string, checkRevoked = false): Promise<DecodedIdToken> {
    const isEmulator = useEmulator();
    return this.idTokenVerifier.verifyJWT(idToken, isEmulator)
        .then((decodedIdToken: DecodedIdToken) => {
        // Whether to check if the token was revoked.
        if (checkRevoked || isEmulator) {
            return this.verifyDecodedJWTNotRevokedOrDisabled(
            decodedIdToken,
            AuthClientErrorCode.ID_TOKEN_REVOKED);
        }
        return decodedIdToken;
        });
}
```

Comment: You're my hero, thanks a lot! 

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, figured out that by BE was pointing to the local emulator, but FE was pointing to the remote Firebase Auth (because of a bug in the code `firebase.auth().useEmulator(...)` wasn't called)

Answer (score 0):

**emragins** answer is great!

One thing which emragins wrote but it wasn't clear for me is that you need to copy the whole text between

- -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
- -----END CERTIFICATE-----\n

and made replace("\n","").

The result from this operation you can paste to the JTW.io. **VERIFY SIGNATURE** field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you need to know if your token is really invalide or if it's an error due to your configuration.

To know easily that, go to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and grab the `kid` parameter in the header of the token. This is the key of a public certificat from google.

Go to the page of the [open key of google](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com), open your browser's console and hit:

```
copy(JSON.parse(document.querySelector('pre').textContent).<kid>.replaceAll('\n', ''))
```

**Make sure to match** the `kid` value from JWT.io with the correct key of the JSON parsed ! Once this command is executed, the certificat is copied in your clipboard so you can directly paste it in the input for VERIFY SIGNATURE encoded and TADA ! Signature really Verified... or not, now you know !

If it's verified.. well sorry body but it's your configuration and for me it was the usage of the auth emulator AND the var env FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST (to comment). I hope you'll find your solution <3

Answer (score 0):

Flutter Firebase JWT Token Invalid Signature Issue

I am currently facing an issue with Firebase authentication in my Flutter application and node js. The problem arises when I try to obtain and print the JWT token using the `getIdToken()` method. The token is being identified as having an invalid signature when checked on `jwt.io`.
so, I come up with this approach:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  get();
}

get() async {
  final tokenResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  String? token = await tokenResult?.getIdToken();

  while (token!.length > 0) {
    int initLength = (token.length >= 500 ? 500 : token.length);
    print(token.substring(0, initLength));
    int endLength = token.length;
    token = token.substring(initLength, endLength);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem with firebase auth emulator and adding to @GeniusHawlah response. Ensure your `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable is not loaded.
Removing this environment variable solved my issue.

Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth/issues/184