# Unable to set custom claims (Firebase NodeJS SDK)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm creating a web-app using React and NodeJS, and I'm using Firebase for authenticating using email/password.
The website has two kinds of logins and registrations handled using the client SDK: one for users, and one for organisations.

I'm trying to set custom claims for a new user registration ({"role": "user"} or {"role": "org"}) using Firebase Functions with the Admin SDK, but I'm facing the following error:

> Error setting custom claims: FirebaseAuthError: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.

I've verified that the UID is being sent correctly to the backend, but I'm unable to set the custom claims.
The below codes are for the User authentication, and I'm trying to set the {"role": "user"} custom claim.

Frontend Code:

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
function emailSignUp(event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed Up
            const user = userCredential.user;
            let formData = new FormData(
                document.getElementById("emailSignUp")
            );

            formData.append("uid", user.uid);

            fetch(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_API_URL}/auth/user/register`,
                {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData,
                }
            )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.status === "error") {
                        throw new Error(
                            "Invalid form input. Please check again."
                        );
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success:", data);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Relevant Backend Code:

```
import { auth } from "../config/firebase.config.js";
//storage and other dependencies are imported as well, and they're working well.

router.post("/register", filesUpload, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { name, email, phone, uid } = req.body;
    const file = req.files[0];
    const filename = file.originalname;
    const extension = filename.split(".").pop();
    const pathToFile = `/user/${email}/profile.${extension}`;
    const storageRef = ref(storage, pathToFile);
    const metadata = {
        contentType: file.mimetype,
    };
    const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(
        storageRef,
        file.buffer,
        metadata
    );

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        photoPathFirestore: pathToFile,
        phone,
    });
    console.log("Successfully created new user in DB!");

    //error occurs on this line, since the admin SDK is not able to find the UID.
    auth.setCustomUserClaims(uid, { role: "user" })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Custom claims set for user");

            response_200(res, "Successfully created new user in DB");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error setting custom claims:", error);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response_500(res, "Error occurred while updating user.");
    }
});
```

Firebase config file:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
dotenv.config();
const adminConfig = require(process.env.PATH_TO_KEY);



const adminApp = initializeApp(adminConfig);
const auth = getAuth(adminApp);

const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.BUCKET_ID,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

export default config;
export { auth };
```

I have tried setting the custom claims when the user attempts to login rather than set them while registration, but even that gives the same error.

Comment: Can you try to just get the user (`getUser(uid)`)? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=en&authuser=0#retrieve_user_data

Comment: Have you considered using the (new-ish) [Firebase Authentication Blocking Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd)  rather than your own backend API?

Comment: Hi, I hadn't come across Blocking Cloud Functions while searching for a solution to this. I will have a go at it.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm not sure whether that'll work as the Admin SDK's getAuth is not able to find the UID generated by the Client SDK. I'll have a try at it after trying the above solution

Comment: @GregFenton Thanks a ton. I upgraded my Firebase Auth to include the Identity Platform features, and deployed the beforeUserCreated function on firebase. This successfully sets the user claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Greg Fenton in the comments, using [Firebase Blocking Functions Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=2nd) did work as an alternative to using the Admin SDK.
Although that solution is perfectly valid, I recently found the cause of the error. **Admin SDK does not support the usage of Firebase Auth Emulator.**
In my case, I used to run `firebase emulators:start` to run the emulators of all the subscribed Firebase services, which would also include the Auth service.

The fix to it would be to run: `firebase emulators:start --only storage,functions,<all_other_services_except_auth>`. This would ensure that your production Auth Service is used.

[Read more about it in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68803294)